# R getsymbols from csv file

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to use getSymbols (quantmod) package in R to download stock prices from a list of stocks that I have in a .csv file.

I have the .csv file imported into R but unsure on how to use getSymbols to read from a .csv file

So I have my list of stock symbols and I want getSymbols to download the price data for each symbol in the list.

Comment: What code did you try?  What didn't work?  Was there an error (if so, what was the `traceback()`)?  What is your `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difficulty I see is that `getSymbols` takes a character vector as inputs, not a factor. So you'll have to be careful and use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading your symbols from a file:

```
csv <- read.csv(textConnection("

SYMBOLS
IBM
GOOG
YHOO

"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(quantmod)
getSymbols(csv$SYMBOLS)
# [1] "IBM"  "GOOG" "YHOO"
```

Alternatively, if you already have your symbols in a factor named `x`, you can run `getSymbols(as.character(x))`.